# Getting stuck in a loop?

Tags: java, loops, authentication, bank

I am making a bank machine code for a project and whenever you log in it gives an error. The part of the code that is doing it is this:

```
if(pincheck == pin){
                loggedin = true;
                pincheck = 0;
                do{
                    System.out.println("Welcome, " + name);
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("Your account balance is $" + balance);
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("Press 1 to deposit funds");
                    System.out.println("Press 2 to withdraw funds");
                    System.out.println("Press 3 to log out");
                    System.out.println("");
                    options = in.nextInt();

                    switch (options) {
                        case 1: System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit?");          // deposit
                                deposit = in.nextFloat();

                                balance = balance  + deposit;
                                deposit = 0;

                                System.out.println("You have deposited funds into your account.");  // withdraw
                                System.out.println("");
                            break;
                        case 2: System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
                                withdraw = in.nextFloat();

                                balance = balance - withdraw;
                                withdraw = 0;

                                System.out.println("You have removed funds from your account.");
                                System.out.println("");
                            break;
                        case 3: System.out.println("Logging out...");                               // log out
                                System.out.println("");
                                loggedin = false;
                            break;
                        default:System.out.println("Please enter a valid number");                  // Invalid number
                            break;
                    }
                }while(loggedin = true);
```

What is happening is to log in you need to put in a number, as pincheck, and if it is equal to the pin that exists it will log you in. I can log in but when I press 3 to log out, it prints logging out and than prints welcome and the whole thing starts again. Can anyone point out where I am getting stuck?

Comment: You do know the difference between assignment `=` and comparison for equality `==`?

Comment: I am relatively new and with something as complex as this if I just googled what I thought was happening it would tell me things that I already knew. Thanks for the help though, I fixed the code and it is working now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is an assignment operator, so you are simply assigning the value (i.e., setting `loggedin=true`), which will always be `true` (because you set to `true`).

So, you are not checking the actual condition in the loop, so you need to correct the `while` condition as shown below which uses `==` operator (used for evaluating the conditional expressions):

```
while(loggedin == true); //use == for condition evaluation
```